# Como puedo limitar al imprimir cierta cantidad de tuplas?

Tags: python, csv

Tengo un archivo CSV que quiero que me imprima 1O tuplas y solamente 10 de una lista de 1000 tuplas , aquí tengo mi código pero no se como decirle que me imprima solo 10 :

```
def TestPERSONAS_SEGUNTIPODESANGRE(contenido):
    print(NOMBRES(contenido, 10))
```

```
def NOMBRES(Doc , n): #Lista por una propiedad
    Almacenamiento_de_datos=[(s.Edad,s.Genero) for s in Doc]
    Diccinario = []
    for s in Almacenamiento_de_datos:
        ordenado = sorted(Almacenamiento_de_datos, key= lambda x:x[1])[:n]
        Diccinario.append(ordenado)
    return Diccinario
```

solo quiero que me imprima 10 tuplas que tengo en Almacenamiento de Datos
Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: `return Diccionario[:n]`

Comment: o puedes crear ir restando 1 a `n` en cada iteración `n-=1` y hacer una comprobación para parar `if not n: break`

Comment: nop me repite la lista 1000 las 10 veces  : return Diccionario [:n]

Comment: Imposible, qué parámetros le pasas?

Comment: osea le pongo ejemplo 2 y me lo repite 2 veces

Comment: a no xd.... me di ceunta que le elime [n] en el codigo ordenado .. listo ya funciono gracias

Comment: jeje, tranquilo, ya me estaba preocupando

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda  :)